# Showing a functor that takes a group to its set of subgroups is not representable

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Let $F:\text{Grp} \rightarrow \text{Set}$ be the functor that takes a group to its set of subgroups. Suppose $A$ is such a representing object, then $\text{Hom}(A,A) \simeq F(A) \Rightarrow \text{Hom}(S_{|A|},S_{|A|}) \simeq F(S_{|A|})$, i.e.

$Aut(S_{|A|}) \underset{\text{Set}}\simeq F(S_{|A|}),$ but $Aut(S_n) = S_n$ for all $n$ other than $2$ and $6$ and $|F(S_{|A|})|>|A|!$ for all $|A|>3$, and so we obtain a contradiction after eliminating the cases $2,3$ and $6.$

Is there (there has to be) a better, more structural proof of this?

Comment: Hi and welcome. (1) What is $F$ on arrows? is it the covariant one or the contravariant one? (2) I don't understand your proof. What happens at the arrow "$\Longrightarrow$"?

Comment: Apologies; that step was entirely unjustified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first problem is that there are two possible such functors: one is covariant, and its effect on a morphism $G \to G'$ is to take a pair $H \subseteq G$ to $f(H) \subseteq G'$. However, there it could also take a pair $H'\subseteq G'$ to $f^{-1}(H') \subseteq G$. This one is the right one in most contexts (for instance in the category of topological spaces, where a pair $U\subseteq X$ could be an open subset). Let me call this functor $F$.

Suppose that there is a group $\Omega$ with the property that for any group $H$, there is a natural isomorphism
$$\hom(H, \Omega) \simeq F(H).$$
Then for every direct limit $\varinjlim H_i$, we have
$$F(\varinjlim H_i) = \hom(\varinjlim H_i, \Omega) \simeq \varprojlim \hom(H_i, \Omega) = \varprojlim F(H_i).$$
In other words a representable functor takes colimits to limits.

But take $$H_i = \frac{1}{p^i}\mathbf Z/\mathbf Z, \quad H_\infty = \varinjlim H_i = \frac{1}{p^\infty}\mathbf Z/\mathbf Z \subseteq \mathbf R/\mathbf Z.$$

The subgroups of $H_\infty$ are all of the form $\frac{1}{p^n}\mathbf Z/\mathbf Z$ for some $n\geq 0$, or the whole group. Thus $F(H_\infty)$ is countable. On the other hand the maps of the direct system $F(H_{i+1}) \to F(H_i)$, induced by inclusion of $\frac{1}{p^{i}}\mathbf Z/\mathbf Z$ in $\frac{1}{p^{i+1}}\mathbf Z/\mathbf Z$, identify in a natural way with

$$\dots \to \{0,1,2\} \to \{0,1\} \to \{0\}$$

where the map $\{0,1,2, \dots, i+1\} \to \{0,1, \dots, i\}$ takes $i+1$ to $0$ and maps every other element to itself. It is easy to see that the inverse limit of this system is uncountable. This shows that $F$ cannot be representable, because $F(H_\infty)$ and $\varprojlim F(H_i)$ do not have the same cardinality.

Comment: Would this be why, in other words, the category of groups has no subobject classifier?

Comment: @dada_cetacean Yes, that's right.

Comment: You probably have a typo in the third line : it must be "$H' \subseteq G'$ to $f^{-1}(H') \subseteq G$". Plus, I think it safe to suppose that the functor of the OP is contravariant as he/she wants to prove it not *representable* (usually, a covariant functor of the form $\hom(\Omega,-)$ is called *corepresentable*, isn't it ?).

Comment: Thanks @Pece. I've seen corepresentable functors being called representable.

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple counterexample using just the fact that $\operatorname{Hom}(-,X)$ takes binary coproducts to products.

Suppose $F \cong \operatorname{Hom}(-,X)$ is representable by a group $X$, then

$$F(\mathbb{Z}/2 * \mathbb{Z}/2) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/2 * \mathbb{Z}/2, X) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/2, X) \times \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/2, X) = F(\mathbb{Z}/2) \times F(\mathbb{Z}/2)$$

Now $\mathbb{Z}/2$ has exactly two subgroups, so the right hand side has cardinality 4. $\mathbb{Z}/2 * \mathbb{Z}/2$ however contains a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$, so has infinitely many subgroups. So the left had side is infinite, a contradiction.

One can do a similar thing to prove that $F$ is not isomorphic to $\operatorname{Hom}(X,-)$ for any group $X$. Plugging in $\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$ we get a contradiction by the fact that $|F(\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2)| = 5$ but$|F(\mathbb{Z}/2) \times F(\mathbb{Z}/2)| = 4$.

Answer (score 2):

Lachlan's argument ruling out the covariant subgroup functor is about as simple as it gets. Here is a similarly simple argument for the contravariant subgroup functor. We will not need any limits or colimits, or even any infinite groups.

Suppose there were a group $\Omega$ such that $F(G) \cong \text{Hom}(G, \Omega)$. Take $G = C_3$. Then $C_3$ has exactly two subgroups, so there must be exactly two homomorphisms $C_3 \to \Omega$, meaning $\Omega$ must have exactly one element of order $3$. But this is impossible, since if $g$ is any such element then so is $g^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Given $$X\ \colon\ \textbf{Grp}^{\text{op}}\ \to\ \textbf{Set}$$ a representable functor, the underlying set of its representing object is $$X\left(\mathbb{Z}\right)\text{,}$$ and the inverse map of its representing object is $$X\left(\mathbb{Z}\right)\overset{X\left(1\ \mapsto\ -1\right)}{\longrightarrow}X\left(\mathbb{Z}\right)\text{.}$$

In the case of the functor at hand, the former set is readily seen to be countable and the latter map the identity, so the only possible representing object is $$\bigoplus_{i=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z}/2\text{,}$$ which clearly doesn’t work (for instance, because there is the wrong number of maps into it from $\mathbb{Z}/3$).